# gridset EPSG:404000

Tags: geoserver, epsg-40400

As I know, gridSet in geoserver is used to convert the coordinate reference system to the tile indexes to make geoWebCache recognize the tiles. However, I used EPSG:404000 in my layer and while I display it as tile layers (cached version) by the means of geoWebCache, I did not add EPSG:404000 gridset.
EPSG:4326 and EPSG:900913 were present by default as gridsets. So, I was expecting geoWebCache not to work because of the missing gridset EPSG:404000, but it worked and map is cached. How is this possible? Did I misunderstand the concept of gridset? If so, can anyone explain it (I read the geoserver official document)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

404000 is an internal GeoServer "joke" on HTTP 404, it's the "coordinate system not found".

Among other funny properties, it can be converted in any other coordinate reference system with no change in the coordinates at all... so you get tiles in "4326" which actually contain the original coordinates of your data, without any transformation.